# How to sort a list by its appearance order and gather the same element together?

Tags: python-3.x

Some points of my question is as follows,thanks for your help:
If there're multiple identical elements,they should end up in the same order as the first appearance in the iterable.
If the element appears in the list only once, the function should return the original list.

```
assert list(appearance_sort([3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 4])) == [3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 6]
assert list(appearance_sort(['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'grape', 'banana'])) == ['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'grape']
assert list(appearance_sort([13, 28, 69, 72])) == [13, 28, 69, 72]
assert list(appearance_sort([])) == []
assert list(appearance_sort([1])) == [1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom `key` for the function `sorted`:

```
def appearance_sort(x):
    return sorted(x, key=lambda y: x.index(y))

var = [1,5,67,1,5,2,1,67,26]
print(var)
print(appearance_sort(var))
```

output:

```
[1, 5, 67, 1, 5, 2, 1, 67, 26]
[1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 67, 67, 2, 26]
```

The reason this works is because `list.index` returns the index of the first instance of that variable.